# Drop Hours, Mins, Secs in Timestamp Error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop the hours/mins/sec in timestamp. I tried using `strftime` but I'm getting an error

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Here's the exact error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

or

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.normalize()
```